# why the content of the struct could be changed in the function

Tags: c, function, recursion, struct, binary-search-tree

This is an operation to inert `X` into a `BinTree`, what confuses me is that why the `BST->Left` can not be changed in step①，however, it can be changed in step② or ster③，I think these three steps are all in the function, why there is a difference between them, I will appreciate it if someone could help me!

```
 BinTree Insert( BinTree BST, ElementType X ){
    if(!BST){
        BST=(BinTree)malloc(sizeof(struct TNode));
        BST->Data=X;①
        BST->Left=NULL;
        BST->Right=NULL;
    }else{
        if(X<BST->Data){
            **BST->Left=**Insert(BST->Left,X);②
        }else{
            **BST->Right=**Insert(BST->Right,X);③
    }
    return BST;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that "the BST->Left can not be changed in step①"?

Comment: If you're going to use a typedef in presented code, you need to show the typedef.  Best solution is to *not* use typedefs.

Comment: With `BST = malloc(sizeof(struct TNode))` there is nothing posted to confirm you allocated the right amount of memory.

Comment: In steps 2 and 3, are those asterisks part of your code, or just an attempt at highlighting?

Comment: The code isn't exactly clear, you are overwriting node pointer with the same or a new value.

Comment: If the `BinTree` is `NULL`, then this function will create and return a newly allocated instance pointed by `BinTree`. The original parameter will *not* be changed since parameters are passed by value. So either change the function signature to accept a pointer to `BinTree`, or create a differentiation between a `BinTree` and a `BinNode`, where `BinTree` will contain only the head `BinNode`.

Comment: I am sorry that I have not asked the question clearly, it is the first time to ask in StackOverflow,  thank you for solving my question, I have found where the problem is! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function deals with a copy of the pointer to the root node of Binary Search Tree. Changing the copy in this statement

```
    BST=(BinTree)malloc(sizeof(struct TNode));
```

does not influence on the original pointer passed to the function as an argument.You have to assign the returned pointer from the function to the original pointer to the root node of the Binary Search Tree like for example

```
BinTree root = NULL;
root = Insert( root, X );
```

In these statements

```
        BST->Left  = Insert(BST->Left,X);
        BST->Right = Insert(BST->Right,X);
```

you are doing the assignment of data ,members Left and Right that are passed to thj function by reference through the pointer BST.

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my problem! I still have confusion that if you mean that the "malloc" statements make step① can not change the BST->Left?

Comment: @陈润泽 It can not change BST->Left of the original pointer passed to the function as an argument because a copy of the pointer is created and the function deals with a copy of the original pointer.